# How to write a file to S3 using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to write a data frame column in .ann format to S3.

Right now I am using the following code to do that.

```
df['user_input'].to_csv(ann_file_path, header=None, index=None, sep=' ')
```

Where ann_file_path is the full path of the .ann file on the Server.

I am getting following error message:

```
[Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/sub_folder/somefile.ann'
```

Why am I getting that?

Also, do I need to use Boto3 to write or can I directly write the file on S3 with full path?

I can think of some authorization might be required for that but the error message seems different from something related to authorization.

Comment: Putting stuff into S3 need credential handshake, you definitely need boto3 or a boto3 wrapper.

Comment: Thank you, I've resolved the problem and posted my answer. I really needed AWS credential handshake :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've resolved. We need AWS handshake using `access_key_id` and `secret_key` for AWS.

Get URL starting from the bucket name (not https:/...), hence get rid of whatever before it.

My URL: `https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/sub_folder/somefile.ann`

Transformed to: `bucket/sub_folder/somefile.ann`

Code to do that: `ann_file_path = ann_file_path.split('.com/', 1)[1]`

Once I got `ann_file_path`, I used [s3fs](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) python library to upload the ann file to the server.

```
bytes_to_write = df['user_input'].to_csv(header=None, index=None).encode()
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(key=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, secret=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
with fs.open(ann_file_path, 'wb') as f:
   f.write(bytes_to_write)
```